# How can i fetch the data of an get api call which is in the format as nested array of object in array of object in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

1. Firstly this is my api data data.

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Request fulfilled, document follows",
    "data": [
        {
            "sn": "ACC-LEW-1JY1-J4X2",
            "created_on": "2022-11-12T07:42:26.531786Z",
            "owner": "devtest01",
            "toy_user_type": 1,
            "shared_status": "Owned",
            "product_data": {
                "id": 179,
                "product_skuid": "any-name",
                "variant_id": "any-id",
                "product_name": "any-product-name",
                "product_type_val": "car-toy",
                "product_category_slug": "stunt-car",
                "desc": null,
            },
            "attribute_data": {
                "toy_distance_travelled": "0",
                "toy_time_played": "0",
                "toy_last_updated": "0",
                "toy_donuts": "0",
                "toy_rash_drives": "0",
                "toy_smooth_drives": "0",
                "toy_top_boost": "0",
                "toy_tank_size": "0",
                "toy_draft_collector": "0",
                "toy_acceleration": "0",
                "toy_braking": "0",
                "toy_name": "",
                "toy_last_played": "",
                "toy_experience": "0",
                "toy_drifts": "0",
                "toy_top_speed": "0",
                "drifts": "0",
                "toy_last_maintainence_distance": "0"
            },
            "game_attribute_data": [
                {
                    "attr_key": "td_distance_travelled",
                    "value": 21,
                    "sync_version": 3
                },
                {
                    "attr_key": "td_time_played",
                    "value": 8,
                    "sync_version": 3
                },
                {
                    "attr_key": "td_drifts_completed",
                    "value": 3,
                    "sync_version": 3
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
    "error": null,
    "server_time": "2022-11-21T12:57:44.319Z"
}
```

2. I want to access the data of game_attribute_data. I tam trying to use map function but I am unable to get the data.
3. This is my api call using fetch method in React.js

```
const allToysData = async () => {
    await fetch(
      `URL`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Authorization: "token"
        },
        redirect: "follow"
      }
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const toysdata = data.data;
        const updatedToysData = toysdata.map(
          (x: {
            created_on: any;
            owner: any;
            shared_status: any;
            sn: any;
            attribute_data: any;
            product_data: any;
            game_attribute_data: any;
          }) => ({
            created_on: x.created_on,
            owner: x.owner,
            shared_status: x.shared_status,
            sn: x.sn,
            toy_drifts: x.attribute_data.toy_drifts,
            toy_time_played: x.attribute_data.toy_time_played,
            toy_last_played: x.attribute_data.toy_last_played,
            toy_last_maintainence_distance: x.attribute_data.toy_last_maintainence_distance,
            product_skuid: x.product_data.product_skuid,
            product_image_1x: x.product_data.data.product_image_1x,
            game_attribute_data: x.game_attribute_data.map(x => x),
          })
        );

        const result = updatedToysData.map(x => x.game_attribute_data);
        setToyAttribute(updatedToysData);
        setArrToys(updatedToysData);
      })
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      .catch(error => console.log(`Error: ${error}`));
  };
```

3. I want to show the data of game_attribute_data in a table. How should I access the data in React.js.

I already tried to get the data using map function but the data is not rendering in table so Please show me where my mistake might be.

Comment: Just give us what is coming in toysdata variable or give codesandbox link.

Comment: As I have stated in my first point of data of my api call its the same data of the toysdata... and i want to access the game_attribute_data from that data how can i do that as to access the inner array of object data from parent array of object data

Comment: Don't mix `await` with `then` callbacks, it's confusing.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to store `game_attribute_data` in the variable `result`, is that correct? You'd need to update state (which it looks like you're doing with `setToyAttribute` and `setArrToys`) so you can access the `game_attribute_data` outside of that `allToysData` function.

Comment: Do you have any errors? When you log these variables before `setToyAttribute`, do you see the correct data? How are you calling this method and rendering the data?

Comment: Yes, but i have to show my created_on till product_image_1x in one table and only game_attribute_data in another table thats why i am storing the game_attribute_data in other variable as to access only that data but i am unable to fetch the game_attribute_data data as its the nested array of object . So this is my question How will i get the game_attribute_data separately..

Comment: @adiga I dont get any arrors in console as i get the complete data of api call but i want to fetch data of game_attribute_data from the api call separately so i can display  it in the table..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    data.data
    .map((item)=>item.game_attribute_data)
    .map((game_attribute_data)=>(game_attribute_data)
    .map((value,key)=>{

    return <tr key={key}>
      <td>{value.attr_key}</td>
      <td>{value.value}</td>
      <td>{value.sync_version}</td>
    </tr>
  }))
}
```

Here's the snippet. View it on fullpage

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

const Example = ({title}) => {
     const [data,setData] = useState({
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Request fulfilled, document follows",
    "data": [
        {
            "sn": "ACC-LEW-1JY1-J4X2",
            "created_on": "2022-11-12T07:42:26.531786Z",
            "owner": "devtest01",
            "toy_user_type": 1,
            "shared_status": "Owned",
            "product_data": {
                "id": 179,
                "product_skuid": "any-name",
                "variant_id": "any-id",
                "product_name": "any-product-name",
                "product_type_val": "car-toy",
                "product_category_slug": "stunt-car",
                "desc": null,
            },
            "attribute_data": {
                "toy_distance_travelled": "0",
                "toy_time_played": "0",
                "toy_last_updated": "0",
                "toy_donuts": "0",
                "toy_rash_drives": "0",
                "toy_smooth_drives": "0",
                "toy_top_boost": "0",
                "toy_tank_size": "0",
                "toy_draft_collector": "0",
                "toy_acceleration": "0",
                "toy_braking": "0",
                "toy_name": "",
                "toy_last_played": "",
                "toy_experience": "0",
                "toy_drifts": "0",
                "toy_top_speed": "0",
                "drifts": "0",
                "toy_last_maintainence_distance": "0"
            },
            "game_attribute_data": [
                {
                    "attr_key": "td_distance_travelled",
                    "value": 21,
                    "sync_version": 3
                },
                {
                    "attr_key": "td_time_played",
                    "value": 8,
                    "sync_version": 3
                },
                {
                    "attr_key": "td_drifts_completed",
                    "value": 3,
                    "sync_version": 3
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
    "error": null,
    "server_time": "2022-11-21T12:57:44.319Z"
    })

return (
 <table >
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Attr Key</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Sync Version</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       {
         data.data
          .map((item)=>item.game_attribute_data)
          .map((game_attribute_data)=>(game_attribute_data)
          .map((value,key)=>{

          console.log(value)
          return <tr key={key}>
           <td>{value.attr_key}</td>
           <td>{value.value}</td>
           <td>{value.sync_version}</td>
         </tr>
       }))
      }
    </tbody>
  </table>

  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Example title="Example using Hooks:" />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your latest comment above, you're only looking for help getting & storing `game_attribute_data` separate from the rest of the API response, correct? If so, here's what I'd recommend:

1. Create a new state variable to store this data. Ex:

```
const [gameAttribData, setGameAttribData] = useState([]);
```

2. In your `allToysData` function, instead of mapping through the API response data, I would probably create a few variables (one for each unique state variable you're going to end up setting), loop through the response data (using `.forEach`), and update each variable for each element you look at. Example for `game_attribute_data`:

```
.then(data => {
  const newGameAttribData = [];

  // Loop through API response data
  data.data.forEach((x: {
    created_on: any;
    owner: any;
    shared_status: any;
    sn: any;
    attribute_data: any;
    product_data: any;
    game_attribute_data: any;
  }) => {
    // Add this element's data to arrays
    newGameAttribData.push(x.game_attribute_data);
  });

  // Update your state variables
  setGameAttribData(newGameAttribData);
});
```

Now you should be able to access `gameAttribData` outside of this function so you can render it to the screen. Hopefully you can adapt the above code for your use (I'm not sure exactly how you're wanting to render it to the screen).